# How to implement CSV Writer in a named temporary - Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, airflow

Basically, I need final a csv file, whose contents look like Header, and then the data:
(Boto3 upload_file does the job of writing temporary file, into csv)

*Expectation:*

```
Name,Code
Adam,12
```

I am able to get this, by using:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="a+t", suffix =".csv", delete=True) as fileName:
   for data in allData:
      fileName.write(data)
      fileName.flush()
```

But, when I am using csv.writer:

```
writer = csv.write(fileName)
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="a+t", suffix =".csv", delete=True) as fileName:
   for data in allData:
      writer.writerow(data)
```

*Reality:*

```
N,a,m,e","C,o,d,e
A,d,a,m","1,2"
```

> Using Python 3.8

`allData` looks like: `[{'name': 'Adam', 'code': '12', 'points': 9.7, 'age': '34'}, {{'name': 'Sam', 'code': '13', 'points': 8.4, 'age': '34'}]`. (There are 1000 data like this, and using a context filters out the values only.)

> A data looks like: Adam,12

Need help writing this with csv writer. I have seen references of StringIO being used to fix similar cases, but do not know how to implement. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the temporary directory.

Here is part of [the introduction about CSV writer objects](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#writer-objects) (bold added):

> A *row* must be **an iterable of strings or numbers** for Writer objects and a dictionary mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers... for DictWriter objects

But you are passing in a *single* string: `"Adam,12"`. So what's going on?

[Strings themselves are iterables](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable) over the characters in the string:

```py
>>> for character in "Adam":
...     print(character)
...
A
d
a
m
```

And since Python doesn't have a distinct character class, each of those single-character values is *also* a string. So strings are iterables of strings.

When you give an iterable of strings to [`csvwriter.writerow()`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow), it writes each string in the iterable to its own column. In this case, that means one-character strings taken from the input.

To get the behaviour you're after, you'll need to pass something like `["Adam", 12]` (not `"Adam,12"`) to the CSV writer. I'm not sure where your inputs are coming from, so there might be a better way to do this, but you could split your strings on the comma as you pass them in:

```py
for data in allData:
    writer.writerow(data.split(","))
```

This works because `"Adam,12".split(",")` returns `["Adam", "12"]`. Note that this won't work properly if your inputs have multiple commas.

**Edit:**

If `allData` is a list of dictionaries, as you show in the edited question, you might be better off with a [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) instead of a regular writer:

> Create an object which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output rows. The *fieldnames* parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the `writerow()` method are written to file *f*.

In other words, something like this:

```py
with open("foo.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ["name", "code", "points", "age"])
    for data in [{"name": "Adam", "code": 12, "points": 0, "age": 18}]:
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Very good explanation.
Yet, as you mentioned, the catch is with respect to multiple commas.

allData looks like: `[{'name': 'Adam', 'code': '12', 'points': 9.7, 'age': '34'}, {{'name': 'Sam', 'code': '13', 'points': 8.4, 'age': '34'}]`
(There are 1000 data like this, and using a context filters out the values only.)

`for data in allData:
    writer.writerow(data.split(","))`

Currently, the csv's contents are like:
`Adam,12,9.7,"34` (Not sure why this " is coming)

I tried `print(data)` and it appears like: `'Adam', '12', '9.7', '34\n'`

Also, 677 lines are coming in the csv.

Comment: Note:

The csv appears like:

`Adam,12,9.7,"34
"
Sam,13,8.4,"34
"`


This could be cause of the `\n` - Also, doing a `fileName.flush()` makes 1000 lines appear.

So, the only issue left is with this escape character appearing out of no where.

Comment: @layman, if you have a list of dictionaries you might want to consider using a `csv.DictWriter` instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: you have a typo here; {{'name'.Maybe this causes the problem